# Where to find an End Portal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I was goofing around in creative mode just because my survival game was a little too intense and I wanted to play without the fear of dying. After a while, building got boring, and then I decided to go and find an End Portal. I've never found one before, but I looked at different tips and got an Ender Eye. I sent a few up from a triangular position. I dug down and found a stronghold. All excited, I decided to go searching. I literally explored every pathway and found absolutely nothing. Despite my many Eyes of Ender, I couldn't find the Portal! What am I doing wrong? I dug down to where it told me to...

Comment: The portal is in there but it is usually positioned to trick you on your way to finding it.

Comment: Ah, alrighty, I'll try again.

Comment: It might also be detached from the main part of the stronghold.  You could use Xray or MCEdit to figure out where it is and move your character to it.

Comment: @EthanBaconGaming you should add your answer below so it can help future users.

Answer (score 3):

The end portal is positioned to try and trick you.  Sometimes the portal may not even be attached to the main part of the stronghold.  You could use xray or mcedit to find it.